# Grails, legacy database fails to get correct type of ID

Tags: grails, grails-orm, legacy-database

There is a lot of problems using tables from a legacy DB.
One is a table with name "RoleType" which has it's ID named "RoleType"

Here is the important fragment of the domain class:

```
class RoleType {
    int roleType
....
    static mapping = {
        table 'RoleType'
        version false
        id column: 'roleType', type:'int', generator:'assigned'
        roleType column: 'RoleType'
```

Error-listing:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertySetterAccessException:
 IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property
 [com.torntrading.legacy.RoleType.id (expected type = java.lang.Long)];
     target = [com.torntrading.legacy.RoleType : (unsaved)], property value = [1] 
setter of com.torntrading.legacy.RoleType.id
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the column for the id, but not which property in the domain is representing it.

`id name: 'roletype', type:'int', generator:'assigned'
roleType column: 'RoleType'`

Should do it

Comment: Thank's, that did it. I'm new to this type of programming and it is so much to learn and I often mix up things. Now I got a new error in the same table, but I think I should put that in a new post.